# Is my PC failing or could it be my monitor?

Tags: printing, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I have a desktop PC (HP Pavilion Elite) that originally came with Windows Vista on it. (I now have Windows 8 Pro installed.) So my PC is at least 4 years old. Also I've noticed that the monitor isn't as clear as it once was. The black seems to be washed out. Twice this week my PC has given me problems. Earlier in the week I was working with it, when it suddenly stopped being able to access the Web via browser, email, etc. I rebooted and that seemed to help. Today while I was trying to print out a Word document it acted very strange. The instant I clicked on the Print button the monitor went blank, and nothing happened. I tried turning the monitor off and back on again, with no effect. I didn't see anything at all on the monitor. So I had to do a hard boot, something I hate to do unless necessary. In looked at disk management in the Computer Management applet, it indicates that the HD is "Healthy".

Now I think that if it were just the monitor failing, the print job would have continued, but nothing printed. So that leads me to think that it's the PC which is beginning to fail. I should also mention that I've checked the event viewer to see what it had to say, and there's nothing in it with regard to the cause of the problem. (The only thing in the event viewer was a message about a the PC being shutdown abruptly.)

My question to you is this, is it likely the PC which is failing, or could it be the monitor failing that somehow was able to prevent the print job from printing?

Comment: So you are able to see things on the monitor after this event? Are you able to print again after this event without the system abruptly shutting down?

Comment: Yes, after doing a hard boot I am able to both see what's on the monitor and print.

Answer (score 0):

It does not sound like the monitor is your only problem, as you are right to think that it would not affect the actual OS of the computer. However, there may be something minorly wrong with the monitor as well as you mentioned the washed out look. This may also just be a problem with the graphics card, or that it is not calibrated properly.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there may be nothing with your hardware, it may just be a software fault, such as a virus or even more mundane problems.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hardware failure, software failure or a combination of both. If you get no display what-so-ever then check the wired connections. If they are intact,then it is more than likely a fried graphics card.

If you are able to log into windows and check all of the information about the hard drive and what not, it may be a virus or a corrupt Win8 installation. It may also be that Win8 does not like the hardware you have in your computer or the drivers are not compatible. This is a difficult question to answer without being able to check all of the hardware and software manually.

Comment: I could run MalwareBytes to see what it shows, just to make certain that a virus isn't what's involved.